# Model with lower AIC has violated assumptions of normality and homoscedasticity

Tags: model-selection, aic, gamma-distribution

I have a repeated measures dataset with multiple plants measured every month.
My DV is growth, IVs are treatment and precipitation.
Since I have measured by month, growth in my data has a high proportion of zeros for each measurement session, and is closer to a gamma distribution.

I'm running a lmer and glmmTMB.

```
modellmer = lmer(growth ~ treatment*precip + (1|plant) + (1|date), REML = T, data = df)

modelglmmTMB = glmmTMB(growth ~ treatment*precip + (1|plant) + (1|date), REML = T, data = growrainp, family = ziGamma(), ziformula = ~1)

AIC(modellmer)
AIC(modelglmmTMB)
```

The lmer model fails both a Shapiro test and Levene test of the residuals. However, the AIC for the lmer model is -5419 and the AIC for the glmmTMB model is -1702.

Is the lmer model better even though it fails the assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same problem with very similar code (comparing a gaussian and hurdle model with right-skewed zero-inflated data), and here is where I am at: AIC score calculations do not evaluate residual normality. Therefore, AIC scores do not discriminate between a horrible non-normal residual plot and a beautiful normally distributed residual plot (a little more on this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142195/does-aic-require-the-residuals-of-the-model-to-be-normally-distributed)). Further, leaning on using linear models with non-normally distributed residuals generally violates the assumptions of that model.

You should 1) choose a model corresponding to what you know about your data, then 2) after evaluating that your model fits your assumptions (e.g., in my case, choosing a model that can leverage zero-inflated, right-skewed, semi-continuous data) use AIC score comparisons to find the ideal model fit comparing models within that model class. My (limited) understanding is that it gets challenging to understand how AIC comparisons calculate AIC scores across model classes (i.e., your modellmer vs. modelglmmTMB) and generally should be avoided. Rather, choose the 'appropriate' model class (it seems like modelglmmTMB based on what I know about your data) then use AIC comparisons when adding and dropping terms within that same model class.

I hope this helps. It would be great for someone more experience to jump in and clarify. I am posting because I have had the same issue and have not found this explicitly addressed elsewhere.